# What is the purpose of the additional metal bar on the latch bolt(tongue)of the door lock?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanical

[image]

Hi.

As you may see at the photo,the tubular latch
has a triangular metal and a thin half cylindrical piece
of metal next to it.
The purpose of the triangular one is obvious,but
What is the purpose of the other half cylindrical piece
(red arrow)?

Comment: It's called a deadlock plunger. You can't get the door to open by pushing on it or sliding a credit card behind it. https://www.go-rbcs.com/articles/the-deadlocking-plunger-weakness

Comment: Any google search will find this.

Comment: Thanks for the useful link.The issue was that i didn't know the name of this specific part,so google didn't help me without typing the name of the part-"deadlock plunger/deadlatch plunger.